# Is it possible to have different zoom for each display for dual-display configuration?

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, multiple-monitors, zooming

It seems for me like it isn't possible, as zoom is changed for both displays simultaneous in "Displays" tool.

ubuntu 18.04, nvidia, one display 4K other 2K

I want to have 200% zoom on 4K display and 100% on 2K display so "resolutions" are equal

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Have the same issue. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: unfortunately no... only solution for me is never buy any 4K display nor any notebook with 4K display

Comment: I found a simple solution. Let me post it.

Comment: what about just changing the resolution from 4k to 2k on the one display?

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick. Replace `$YOUR_4K_SCREEN` with the name of your output. You can play with the scaling factor until it's comfortable for you.

```
xrandr --output $YOUR_4K_SCREEN --scale 0.5x0.5
```

If anyone knows how to make this persist let us know.

If you encounter overlapping issue on second monitor use arandr to set screen position

`sudo apt install arandr`

Comment: You can persist this by exporting the resulting script from arandr, adding your custom scaling command (such as in your answer) above the arandr generated one (but below the bash shabang), and adding it into your GUI startup commands. e.g. if you're using GNOME, you can follow this thread for how to do that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247706/start-script-when-gnome-starts-up

Answer (score 0):

Log out, and log again, but just before use the little cog, choose Ubuntu Wayland. And then in your configuration of screen , you'll be able to select different scale for different monitors.

Answer (score -1):

So I was having a similar problem, using Ubuntu 18.04 on an HP Spectre laptop with 2560x1440 at 200% magnification and have an Acer display at 1600x900. I was trying to get the Acer display to not display at 200% in the setting and it would not work. I ended up running this (Thanks dsklosr)

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --scale 2x2
```

and now have 200% magnification on my laptop display and 100% on my attached Acer display :)

If someone knows a sudo command to make it permanent I will be all set